# When getting a repo object from the GitHub API, what does the network_count field represent?

Tags: github, github-api

The [docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) for the api don't specify it. Here is an example of the response from the api: https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/grit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `network_count` field represents the number of repositories in the network. Basically, it's the number of repositories shown on the Network > Members page, minus the repository itself.

https://github.com/mojombo/grit/network/members

Comment: What does it mean though? Forks including all the descendent forks?